# Looping dates in a feature class comparing them to date 1 month from now in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, datetime

I thought this would be quite a simple task but I'm struggling. I want to loop over a date field in feature class looking for dates 1 month from today. It appears that I'm running into a simple date format issue but not sure what specifics to ask Google to figure it out for myself.

```
    #Import Modules
    import arcpy
    import datetime
    from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

    #Today's date/one month from now
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    checkDate = today + relativedelta(months=+1)

    #Featureclass variable
    fc = "C:\\Users\\99_Misc.gdb\\Check_v0"

    #Loop over expiry dates subtracting checkDate from date
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(extents,'Expiry_Date') as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row - checkDate

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/test.py", line 24, in <module>
    row - checkDate
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'datetime.datetime'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Do I need to make my date types consistent in some way?

Comment: Try changing to  `row[0] - checkDate`

Comment: `row` is a tuple, `checkDate` is a datetime object.  I'm not clear why the error is reported from line 24 when there are not that many lines in the code you have presented.

Comment: Can you show us what format "Expiry_Date" is in?

Comment: You can use `type()` on `row[0]` to show us what format "Expiry_Date" values are in.

Comment: @PolyGeo thanks for your comments. In an attempt to keep things simple I removed print statements I'd written whilst trying to figure out a solution myself, but wrongly copied the error message from the console hence the line number discrepancy.

Comment: @Damien for future reference, if you trim your code down for pasting it in here, be sure to test it and then paste the error from that snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `row - checkDate` to be `row[0] - checkDate`.  The `row` is a python tuple containing values from all specified fields in your cursor.  Even if there's only one field it still records it as a tuple.  So the `row[0]` gets the actual value (your date), rather than the tuple.

```
#Loop over expiry dates subtracting checkDate from date
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(extents,'Expiry_Date') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print row[0] - checkDate
```

The `print row[0] - checkDate` will return something like:

```
-1 day, 12:55:14.572000
-31 days, 12:55:14.572000
-62 days, 12:55:14.572000
```

Comment: thank you. Your solution worked a treat. Had a feeling it would be something quite simple.